# How to Set Up Xcode with Remote Git Repository

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

so I just installed a new remote git repository on one of our servers and want to move our old projects there. Our existing projects have local git repositories, and we can add  repos from the server, but how do we move our existing projects onto the server?

Any ideas?

Comment: ok fixed it. just decided to stop using bonobo and everything works fine. now just need to figure out how to put a password on gitaspx...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would do these steps:

Make the individual repositories on the server.

```
git clone --bare nameofrepo
```

On the actual repo, add the remote to the repository from which you want to send up work:

```
git remote add origin <url to your remote>
```

Now push your branch for your work:

```
git push origin master
```

Repeat for any other branches you want to have pushed to the central repo.

The URL in the first command can also be a regular file path. Most solutions, however are through an SSH connection.

Comment: how would I use the line "git remote add origin <url to your remote>" on a specific repo? would I have to cd to the folder I want to upload?

Comment: Yes, you need to be in the (local) git repository when you run "git remote add ..." and "git push ...".

Comment: ok, so i was able to run all the commands and have all my files uploaded to my server, but for some reason my commits in Xcode don't upload. any ideas why? - also, when i go to repositories in organizer, the new "origin"remote has nothing in it, and Xcode crashes when i try to set the username/ password... any ideas?

Comment: figured it out: needed to set up webdav on my iis server

Answer (score 1):

After creating your Xcode project, **cd** to that directory
and make sure you are on the **master** branch
Type:

```
git remote add origin <URL-of-your-GitHub-repository>
git pull
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
git merge
git commit -m "Merging with remote”
git push
```

Now your new project has been pushed to the remote GitHub directory.